# How to push a string in typescript file?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a class called

```
export class Channel {
  name: string
}
```

I have an object `items: Channel[];`

I have an array `test[] = { "one", "two", three" }`

How do I push these texts to items object.

Comment: I'm having a hard time following your syntax. If you want to push into an array your items array needs to be initialized. Can you share a better representation of the code? And use the code styling SO provides?

Comment: `test` isn't a proper object. Even if you drop it inside square brackets, it will be still invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Channel class is only being used for type checking as far as I can tell.

Channel.ts

```
export class Channel {
  name: string;
}
```

Items.ts

```
import { Channel } from './Channel';

const items: Channel[] = []; // initialize to empty array
const test: string[] = ["one", "two", "three"];

// because 'test' is an array of strings we need to convert each item
// to be a Channel

const channels = test.map(t => { return { name: t } as Channel }); // the 'as Channel' part is only for type checking

// assign 'channels' to 'test'
test.push(...channels);
```

Here's a working example: http://codepen.io/kenhowardpdx/pen/dNLeoJ?editors=0012